# How to setup autolayout so UILabel resizes and other views move as necessary

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a label that wraps in portrait mode (2 lines), but not in landscape (1 line):

[image: portrait]

[image: landscape]

I would like to set up autolayout so that the label can resize as necessary and move the other views up or down depending on the label.  However, I don't quite understand how to set this up within the iOS storyboard.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: you have to set the vertical spacing of views with respect to the label.

Comment: This is easy. _What_ don't you understand about it? What have you done, and what is happening or failing to happen in response?

Comment: I'm new to iOS development, so it isn't easy (yet) for me.  I have set the # of lines to 0, turned on Word Wrap, and tied the Leading side to the left edge of the screen and the Trailing side to the right edge of the screen.  However, when I preview portrait and landscape modes, the UILabel doesn't change.  I was going to stack the other views once I got the UILabel to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly there two things that you are looking for:

1. Resize the label based on the text length using storyboard, this can be achieved by going into the attribute inspector and setting `Lines` to `0` and `Line break Mode` to `WordWrap`. Also attached a picture for reference
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxaVB.png).
   Just some extra info, you can also be achieve it programmatically, by using the code below:

   ```
   myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
   myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
   ```
2. Moving other views based on the size of your label, this can be achieved by setting up constraints against the views that you want to be pushed. You can refer to Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html), easy to grasp and shows how to do it step by step.

Comment: Thank you for the link to Apple's documentation.  I'm was having the most trouble with the UILabel (see my comment above), but the Reset to Suggested Constraints seems to have done the trick.  I don't understand what it did differently than what I did, but I'll investigate further.  Also, the storyboard doesn't seem to be showing exactly what the views look like after the app is built and run in the simulator.  Everything looks good in the simulator, but the views are all scrambled in the storyboard.  Is that typical?

Comment: You're welcome. So, what reset to suggested constraints does is that it override your given constraints and adds system defined constraints that satisfy the view. The constraints should be dictated by the user and not by the system. After reading your last comment on your question. I think you forgot to add constraints form the top and bottom of your label to the surrounding views, which I think the system added for you when you did reset to suggested constraints. The storyboard should be close to what the views should look like in your simulator/device. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: One suggestion that I would like to give you is, if you are using iOS 9 and above you can utilize UIStackView which pretty much takes care of handling constraints between the views for you and is comparatively easy to use. This is a good resource for learning [stack views](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2)